# How to show product subcategory in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Subcategory is not showing on WordPress page. 
I'm using WooCommerce - excelling eCommerce WordPress plugin. 
This is plugin  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

I have change woocommerce plugin file `archive- product.php` as

```
<?php 
    woocommerce_product_subcategories(array('force_display' => true));      
    woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID(32); 
    woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_NAME('Parent Category');
?>
```

Comment: Did you have any code to post?

Comment: I have change  woocommerce plugin file archive- product.php  
                                                                                                        <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(array('force_display' => true)); ?>
woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID(32);

woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_NAME('Parent Category');